# how to perform the next task (add condition and pass parameters from 2 datasources to one stored procedure)

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have excel file with 2 sheets. What i need to do:

1. Read Id from the 1st sheet (just one row, one column)
2. Check whether there is a record in db with such id (figure 1)

[image]

3. If previous condition is met, then i need to read data from 2nd sheet (many rows)
4. Pass data from #3 and id from #1 to stored procedure and execute it.

   This figure reads 2nd sheet with user data and passes to stored procedure.
   [image]

But i don't understand how to combine it into one scheme to make items 1-4 work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So ... if I think I understand your question correctly ... what you want to do is store that Excel ID value in a variable, and then add it to your data flow in part 2 as a Derived Column.

So your package should look like this:

**EXECUTE SQL TASK**

ConnectionType EXCEL, Connection is your Excel connection, Result Set is "Single row", SQL Statement is "select top 1 * from [SheetNameWithDataSourceIDGoesHere$]". Result Set maps result name "0" to a Variable Name (let's call it User::DataSourceID.)

**DATA FLOW TASK**

SOURCE: Excel sheet

DERIVED COLUMN: Call it DataSourceID, value is User::DataSourceID.

LOOKUP: Against wherever you're looking up data sources. No Match Output heads on to your Data Conversion and stored procedure.

---

If you want to get fancy, you could include a second *Excecute SQL Task* after the first one, use an expression for the *SQLStatementSource* to run against your database table containing the data source IDs.

Something like:

```
"select count(1) as DataSourceIDExists from DATASOURCELOOKUPTABLE where DataSourceID = " + (DT_WSTR,50)@User::DataSourceID
```

And then map that to a "Single row" ResultSet, with result name "0" mapped to *User::DataSourceIDExists*. Then after that task, use a precedence constraint with an expression of

```
(User::DataSourceIDExists == 0)
```

To determine if you even go down to the *Data Flow Task* to load Excel data. Since it sounds like you're not a full-on SSIS expert just yet, this might serve as an excellent learning opportunity.